# why JavaScript v8 engine is designed to can only Initialize once per process?

Tags: android, v8, embedded-v8

My Android project uses JavaScript v8 engine. we only uses v8 engine in a few pages, not all over the app's lifetime. We found that JavaScript v8 engine occupy a lot of memory (over 100M), and created some worker threads. Because we only use v8 in a few pages, so when close these pages, we try to dispose v8 like below:

```
v8::V8::Dispose();
v8::V8::ShutdownPlatform();
```

After calling these methods, memory usages decrease dramatically as below:
[image]

Then when enter v8 pages again, we need to initialise v8 again as below:

```
v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
v8::V8::Initialize();
```

But after initialize v8, code will crash at below:

```
art_sigsegv_fault 0x0000007c07a7c2e8
art::FaultManager::HandleFault(int, siginfo*, void*) 0x0000007c07a7c7fc
art::SignalChain::Handler(int, siginfo*, void*) 0x0000005619525e54
<unknown> 0x0000007e9e6668b0
v8::internal::wasm::WasmEngine::AddIsolate(v8::internal::Isolate*) 0x0000007b97ddc608
v8::internal::wasm::WasmEngine::AddIsolate(v8::internal::Isolate*) 0x0000007b97ddc608
v8::internal::Isolate::Init(v8::internal::ReadOnlyDeserializer*, v8::internal::StartupDeserializer*) 0x0000007b97b25b80
v8::internal::Isolate::InitWithSnapshot(v8::internal::ReadOnlyDeserializer*, v8::internal::StartupDeserializer*) 0x0000007b97b260b0
v8::internal::Snapshot::Initialize(v8::internal::Isolate*) 0x0000007b97dc07b4
v8::Isolate::Initialize(v8::Isolate*, v8::Isolate::CreateParams const&) 0x0000007b97aa1270
v8::Isolate::New(v8::Isolate::CreateParams const&) 0x0000007b97aa1370
se::ScriptEngine::init() ScriptEngine.cpp:412
se::ScriptEngine::start() ScriptEngine.cpp:588
Game::init() Game.cpp:59
(anonymous namespace)::createGame(ANativeWindow*) JniCocosActivity.cpp:57
(anonymous namespace)::preExecCmd(signed char) JniCocosActivity.cpp:87
(anonymous namespace)::glThreadEntry() JniCocosActivity.cpp:134
decltype(std::__ndk1::forward<void (*)()>(fp)()) std::__ndk1::__invoke<void (*)()>(void (*&&)()) type_traits:4353
void std::__ndk1::__thread_execute<std::__ndk1::unique_ptr<std::__ndk1::__thread_struct, std::__ndk1::default_delete<std::__ndk1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)()>(std::__ndk1::tuple<std::__ndk1::unique_ptr<std::__ndk1::__thread_struct, std::__ndk1::default_delete<std::__ndk1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)()>&, std::__ndk1::__tuple_indices<>) thread:342
void* std::__ndk1::__thread_proxy<std::__ndk1::tuple<std::__ndk1::unique_ptr<std::__ndk1::__thread_struct, std::__ndk1::default_delete<std::__ndk1::__thread_struct> >, void (*)()> >(void*) thread:352
__pthread_start(void*) 0x0000007e997b4d50
__start_thread 0x0000007e9975528c
```

After digging v8 code, I found it seems v8 allow only initialize once per process. Because there are code like below:

```
bool V8::Initialize() {
  InitializeOncePerProcess();
  return true;
}
```

and below:

```
  Isolate::InitializeOncePerProcess();

#if defined(USE_SIMULATOR)
  Simulator::InitializeOncePerProcess();
#endif
  CpuFeatures::Probe(false);
  ElementsAccessor::InitializeOncePerProcess();
  Bootstrapper::InitializeOncePerProcess();
  CallDescriptors::InitializeOncePerProcess();
  wasm::WasmEngine::InitializeOncePerProcess();
```

So my question is: why v8 is designed to initialize only once. What should I do if I need to dispose and initialize again? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

V8 uses the concept of "isolates", which are independent instances of it. Try creating and destroying those as needed, instead of attempting to dispose and re-initialize the entire engine. That should give you almost all of the memory savings, while avoiding any issues arising from using V8 in ways that it wasn't designed for.